# Every set of ring homomorphisms is linearly independent in $B$-module $B^A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ and $B$ be integral domains (with unity). Consider a subset $S$ of the $B$-module $M = B^A$ (all functions from $A$ to $B$ with pointwise operations) such that every element of $S$ is a ring homomorphism (preserving unity) from $A$ to $B$. I want to show that $S$ is then linearly independent in $M$.

Can someone give me a hint on how to prove this?

> **What I have done so far**:
>
> I tried induction on the number of elements in a linear combination:
> if $\lambda_1f_1(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A$ then obviously $\lambda_1 = 0$ if we put $x = 1$. Now, let this statement be true for any $n$ ring homomorphisms. Let $$0 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} \lambda_if_i(x)$$ Then we have for all $i = 1,...,n+1$ that $\lambda_i \neq 0$ (otherwise we would have a linear combination with strictly less than $n+1$ terms and could apply induction hypothesis) and
> $$\lambda_if_i(x) = -\sum_{\stackrel{j = 1}{j \neq i}}^{n+1} \lambda_j f_j(x)$$
> (From this it is easy to see that $\ker f_k = \ker f_l$ since B is an integral domain, but I don't know if it has any use). If for some $i$ we have that $\lambda_i$ is not a unit, then we can pick some proper maximal ideal $L \unlhd B$ such that $\lambda_iB \subset L$ and compose this equation with the projection $\pi : B \to B/L$
> $$0 = -\sum_{\stackrel{j = 1}{j \neq i}}^{n+1} \pi(\lambda_j) (\pi \circ f_j)(x)$$ Since $B/L$ is also an integral domain, I would like to apply the induction hypothesis on the set $\{\pi \circ f_1,..., \pi \circ f_{n+1}\}\setminus\{\pi \circ f_i\}$, but I don't know if it leads me anywhere since $\pi(\lambda_j) = 0$ does not imply $\lambda_j = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_if_i=0\tag{*}
$$
with $f_1,\dots,f_n$ pairwise distinct and $n>1$ (the case $n=1$ is already done). Choose $y\in A$ such that $f_1(y)\ne f_n(y)$. Evaluate (*) at $x$ and $yx$:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if_i(x)=0\\
&\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if_i(y)f_i(x)=0
\end{align}
Multiply by $f_n(y)$ the first equality and subtract the second one:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i(f_n(y)-f_i(y))f_i(x)=0
$$
for all $x$. Can you finish?